# Running AUCTeX on Windows - problem writing files

Tags: windows, auctex, viewers

I love AUCTeX, and use it on an Ubuntu machine all the time. Right now, however, I am stuck with a Windows machine and would like some help getting around a problem. Whenever I try to compile my .tex file with C-c C-c and the file is also open in the viewer, I get the error that "I can't write on abc.pdf".

Of course, I can close the viewer every time I want to compile, but I hope that someone knows how to get around this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your PDF-viewer is the Adobe Reader (as it often is on Windozs), the Windozs version locks the PDF-file when it is open. Change the viewer to f.ex. [Sumatra PDF](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/software/sumatrapdf/free-pdf-reader.html).